# sql - Show Event if date is between two dates Code Igniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have an events table with fields:

- event_name
- start_date
- end_date

I want to display the event if the date today is between the start_date and the end_date.

And the start_date should be greater than today to display the current event.

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$event = $this->db->where("start_date >=",$today)
    ->where("end_date <=",$today)
    ->order_by("from_date","asc")
    ->get("events");
```

I have 2 sample events:

```
---event_name--------start_date--------end_date---
    event1         2016-01-19        2016-02-20
    event2         2016-02-29        2016-02-29
```

I want only to show the event that today date is between the start_date and end_date of the event. But one of the event keep showing.

I have edited my question. The field should be start_date and end_date.

Sorry.

Comment: `from_date` to `start_date` and `to_date ` to `end_date` :) 
What error you getting in this  ??

Comment: There is no error. My problem is the event keep on showing even if the end date is done.

Comment: what is field type of `start_date` and `end_date` ??

Comment: it is DATE "Y-m-d" format

Comment: consider using `where(array("start_date <=" => $today,"end_date >=" => $today ))`....

Comment: If you want to display the events where today is between `start_date` and `end_date`, then standard logic says that `start_date` will never be both before AND after today. Which of the two dates is later? I assume `end_date` is the later date. Clarify?

Comment: @asHkER do you already try my answer?

Comment: @Yoshioka yes. It still show an event today. No event should be shown today.

Comment: @asHkER its weird, i tried it and work.

Comment: @Yoshioka Im sorry, I was just confused with start_date and end_date. I have put the fields in opposite ways. Thanks

Comment: @asHkER you're welcome, glad it help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to swap `<=` and `>=`

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$event = $this->db->where("start_date <=",$today)
                  ->where("end_date >=",$today)
                  ->order_by("start_date","asc")
                  ->get("events");
```